# For loop warning: "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length" with two dataframes

Tags: r, for-loop, warnings

I am trying to create a new vector by applying a transformation to a variable in one of my dataframe based on data from another dataframe.

I have two dataframes df1 and df2. df1 and df2 have different dimension, I have over 20,000 rows in df1 and 76 rows in df2.
df1 is my original dataset. I created df2 for Ag_ppm as follow:

```
df2 <- df1%>%
  filter(!is.na(Ag_ppm)) %>%
  group_by(Year,Zone, SubZone) %>%
  summarise(
    n = sum(!is.na(Ag_ppm)),
    min = min(Ag_ppm),
    max = max(Ag_ppm),
    mean = mean(Ag_ppm),
    sd = sd(Ag_ppm),
    iqr = IQR(Ag_ppm),
    Q1 = quantile(Ag_ppm, 0.25),
    median = median(Ag_ppm),
    Q3 = quantile(Ag_ppm, 0.75),
    LW = min(Ag_ppm > (quantile(Ag_ppm, .25)-1.5*IQR(Ag_ppm))),
    UF = quantile(Ag_ppm, .75) + 1.5*IQR(Ag_ppm))
```

Here is what the first rows of each data frames look like:

```
head(df1, n=5)

# A tibble: 5 x 12
  Year  Zone            SubZone         Au_ppm Ag_ppm Cu_ppm Pb_ppm Zn_ppm As_ppm Sb_ppm Bi_ppm Mo_ppm
  <chr> <chr>           <chr>            <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 1990  BugLake         BugLake          0.007    3.7     17     27     23      1      1     NA      1
2 1983  Johnny Mountain Johnny Mountain  0.01     1.6     71     63    550      4     NA     NA     NA
3 1983  Khyber Pass     Khyber Pass      0.12    11.5    275    204   8230    178      7     60     NA
4 1987  Chebry          Ridge Line Grid  0.05     2.2     35     21    105     16      6     NA     NA
5 1987  Chebry          Handel Grid      0.004    1.3     29     27    663     45      2     NA     NA

head(df2, n=5)
# A tibble: 5 x 14
# Groups:   Year, Zone [3]
  Year  Zone            SubZone         n   min   max  mean    sd   iqr    Q1 median    Q3    LW    UF
  <chr> <chr>           <chr>       <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1 1981  Chebry          Handel         52   0.6   5.1 1.83  0.947 0.925  1.2    1.6   2.12     1  3.51
2 1981  Imperial Metals Handel         24   0.9   6.9 2.81  1.43  1.35   1.95   2.65  3.3      1  5.33
3 1983  Chebry          Chebry          5   0.7   3.7 1.78  1.19  0.9    1.2    1.2   2.1      1  3.45
4 1983  Chebry          Handel         17   0.1   0.7 0.318 0.163 0.2    0.2    0.3   0.4      1  0.7 
5 1983  Chebry          Handel Grid   225   0.1  16   0.892 1.33  0.7    0.3    0.6   1        1  2.05
```

I want to apply the following equation to my column Ag_ppm in df1 using the median and IQR calculated for each subgroup in df2:
Z = (X - median)/IQR

For that purpose, I wrote:

```
# Initialize Ag_std vector with NA values
Ag_std <- rep(NA, times = nrow(df1))     

# Populate Ag_std vector with standardized Ag values
Ag_std <- 
  for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) {
    if (!is.na(df1$Ag_ppm[i])) { 
        filter(df2, Zone == df1$Zone[i], Year == df1$Year[i], 
           SubZone == df1$SubZone[i]) 
        Ag_std[i] <- (df1$Ag_ppm[i] - df2$median)/df2$iqr
    }
  }
```

But the loop does not work (it returns a NULL vector) and I have this warning:

```
1: In Ag_std[i] <- (df1$Ag_ppm[i] - df2$median)/df2$iqr :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I've looked similar questions, and I did not find an answer that would work for me. Any help would be much appreciated!

If there are better ways of achieving the same without a loop (I'm sure there are, e.g. apply()), I would appreciate such comments as well. Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with the alternatives to be able to implement them quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done relatively easily in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(df1)

#function to apply
fun <- function(x) (x - median(x)) / diff (quantile( x, c(.25, .75)))

# create a new column with desired result
DT[, Ag_std := fun(Ag_ppm), by = list(Year, Zone, SubZone)]
```

Also, I think your loop can be fixed by assigning the result of 'filter' to a temporary object

```
  for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) {
    if (!is.na(df1$Ag_ppm[i])) { 
        temp.var <- filter(df2, Zone == df1$Zone[i], Year == df1$Year[i], 
           SubZone == df1$SubZone[i]) 
        Ag_std[i] <- (df1$Ag_ppm[i] - temp.var$median)/temp.var$iqr
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't think that  your data.table solution would work, because it doesn't call df2, which I need, because it has the median and IQR for the different datasets within my dataset. I have tried to assign a temporary variable like you suggested, but I get an empty vector and I do not understand why.

Comment: If df2 was created from df1 it should work, since the DT version calculates these stats on the fly for each group. If df2 is from a different dataset then it wouldn't work.

Comment: Ooh, I see. I have not used data.table before, only the dyplr library. So powerful! Thank you, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `df2` as a seperate dataframe, you can `join` and `mutate`:

```
df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("Year", "Zone", "SubZone")) %>%
  mutate(Z = (Ag_ppm - median) / iqr)
```

In fact, you could have generated info in df2 in df1 itself using `summarise`

Comment: df1 and df2 are of different dimensions, and my df2 is a summary for my column Ag_ppm, but I have many others. I don't want to end up with a data frame that has 10,000s rows and 100s variables! I've edited my question, hopefully it is a bit clearer.